# IOS: change firmware

Tags: xcode, ios, firmware

I installed Xcode 4 with IOS 4.3 and I create an small application, but if I want set firmware 4.2? How can I do? In build menu I can choose only 4.3 for IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always set `Base SDK` to the `Latest iOS`. This will ensure compatibility with current and future versions.

To make your app run on older versions of the OS, set the `Deployment Target` to the desired version in your Active Target's settings.